# Why is the @ symbol escaped in this Perl regular expression?

Tags: regex, perl, escaping

I'm currently covering Perls RegExps and on the whole understand it I think. Escaping characters I have also grasped I think, ie testing for a backslash, denoteable by m/\/ in that the backslash needs to be proceeded buy the \ character first to tell perl in this instance to search for it as apposed to it's usual meaning.

What I don't understand with the code below I have is, this pattern match and why (\) is used when testing the email address with @ symbold (in the if statement expression). I'm not aware @ is a special character needing escaping or have I missed something?.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

EMAIL:
{
print("Please enter your email address: ");
$email = <STDIN>;
  if ($email !~ /\@/)
  {
    print("Invalid email address.\n");
    redo EMAIL;
  }
  else
  {
    print("That could be a valid email address.");
  }
}
```

Comment: It appears `/@/` means the same as `/\@/`.  But watch out:  `/@x/` is very different from `/\@x/`.

Comment: Oh ok, I have further reading to do but I'll bear it in mind. Many thanks for your assistance!!. I'd done my best to try and resolve it, reading back, without asking, for asking sake or idleness but I was struggling. Thanks again

Comment: Heh, what do you do if you want to match a reference to `@x`? :) Assign it to a scalar and stop trying to be so clever!

Comment: Personally, I just escape everything that is not a number or letter in a regular expression.  Paranoid I guess.

Answer (score 13):

It's probably escaped to avoid being interpreted as an array sigil. It's not strictly necessary but it's a tough habit to break.

Examples:

```
$e = "\@foo";
if ($e =~ /@/) {
  print "yay\n";
}
```

yields:

```
yay
```

Same with:

```
$e = "foo";
if ($e =~ m@foo@) {
  print "yay\n";
}
```

Comment: Yeah I'd heard either // or ## was used but didn't know @@ could be also. Brilliant. Thanks, very helpful.

Comment: @Mike Thornley You can even match braces such as: `m{...}` -- I think this is covered in perlop under "Quote and Quote-Like". If not there, then in perlsyn. The "issue" with the @ is the regular expression literals fall under the "interpolated quote" category unless in the `m'...'`, etc. form.

Comment: @Mike Ahh: [The Gory Details Of Parsing Quoted Constructs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Gory-details-of-parsing-quoted-constructs) from perlop covers it a bit ;-)

Comment: @Mike Thomley: You can use literally ANY character as your delimeter. Braces/brackets need to be matched (instead of duplicated), and letters/numbers need to have a space between them and the quoting operator (and possibly the string too). Personally, I recommend sticking with / or ! or # or some sort of bracket.

Comment: A nifty way to use the `qw` quote-like operator is `qw wq qw`. That would give you a list of two strings, `q` and `q`. See, `w` is the delimiter to `qw`, so it would normally be written as `qw /q q/`.

Comment: THIS IS THE KIND OF THING THAT GIVES PERL PROGRAMMERS A BAD NAME

Answer (score 9):

@ is not a reserved character with respect to regexes, but it is for perl (it's the array symbol)

Answer (score 5):

In Perl, you can escape any potential regex metacharacter and be guaranteed it's a literal.

Also, for `@`, it's the array sigil, so if there's any chance of it being mistaken for an `@/` variable, it's worth escaping.

Answer (score 5):

Arrays are interpolated into both double-quoted strings and regexes in Perl, with the special variable `$"` (by default a space character) going between each element:

```
my @array = ('a', 'b', 'c');
print "@array";  # prints "a b c"
print "a b c" =~ /@array/;  # prints "1"
```

I rarely use this feature, but occasionally it comes in handy, for example:

```
sub line_matches_words {
    my ($line, @words) = @_;
    local $" = '[ \t]+';
    return $line =~ /^[ \t]*@words[ \t]*$/;
}
```